# Cakephp Datatables SSP Group By

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I have the following code. I want to execute a group by clause on datatables SSP class on serverside.

```
$loggedInUser = $this->Auth->user();
        $loggedInUser = CommonUtil::DataTableToArr($loggedInUser);
        $this->autoRender = false;

        $table = <<<EOT
        (select UserId , sum(GrossRate) as UserRate, sum(UserRate) , sum(OfferwallRate) , 
        sum(NumberOfTasks) from offerwalldb.offerwall_transaction_by_users                
        group by UserId
        ) tmp 
        EOT;

        $primaryKey = 'Id';
        Log::debug($this->request->data);
        $columns = array(
            array( 'db' => 'UserId', 'dt' => 0, 'field' => 'UserId' ),
            array( 'db' => 'UserRate',  'dt' => 1, 'field' => 'Rate' )

        );

        $result = SSPGroup::simple($_GET, CommonUtil::$dbDetails, $table, $primaryKey, $columns );        
        Log::debug($result);
        echo json_encode(
            $result
        );
```

and I am getting the following error

```
syntax error, unexpected end of file in
```

I have also tired the extended version present on github but that is not working as well. Also how can i add a where clause to it?

I am using cakephp3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this great library to do

https://datatables.ozdemir.be/group-by

Anyone stuck should have a look on this.

```
use Ozdemir\Datatables\Datatables;
use Ozdemir\Datatables\DB\MySQL;

public function GetDataByUsers()
    {
        $loggedInUser = $this->Auth->user();
        $loggedInUser = CommonUtil::DataTableToArr($loggedInUser);
        $this->autoRender = false;

        $config = [
            'host'     => 'localhost',
            'port'     => '3306',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'database' => 'offerwalldb'
        ];

        $dt = new Datatables(new MySQL($config));

        $dt->query('select UserId ,SUM(GrossRate) as GrossRate
                    from offerwalldb.offerwall_transaction_by_users                
                    group by UserId');

        echo $dt->generate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the example of [Cakephp Datatables SSP Group By](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-using-where-join-and-group-by-with-ssp-class-php/)

please verify you code with this example make you are not missing any step or syntax!!!.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `heredoc` syntax to delimit string. `EOT` is the identifier.

From the [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc),

> The closing identifier must begin in the first column of the line

So instead of

```
        EOT;
```

it should be

```
EOT;
```

Further from the Docs

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.

Comment: That solved the issue with incorrect syntax, Now the error comes up as Incorrect table name

Comment: Please check the name of the table in your DB. You are using `offerwall_transaction_by_users`

Comment: the table name is correct. It gives the subquery as invalid name.

Comment: I am not sure where you are getting the error. I don't see any subquery.